# RegExp JS regarding sequential patttern matching

Tags: regex

P.S: --> I know there is an easy solution to my needs, and I can do it that way but, -- I am looking for a "diff" solution for learning sake & challenge sake. So, this is just to solve an algorithm in a lesser traditional way.

I am working on solving an algorithm, and thought I had everything working well but one use case is failing. That is because I am building a regexp dynamically - now, my issue is this.

I need to match letters sequentially up until one doesn't match, then I just "match" what did match sequentially.

so... lets say I was matching this:

```
"zaazizz"

with this: /\bz[a]?[z]?/ 

"zizzi".match(/\bz[z]?[i]?/)
```

currently, that is matching with a : [zi], but the match should only be [z]

zzi only matches "z" from the front of "zizzi", in that order zzi - I now I am using [z]? etc... so it is optional.. but what I really need is match sequentially.. I'd only get "zi" IF from the front, it matched: zzi per my regex.... so, some sort of lookahead or ?. I tried ?= and != no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. So when you have "abcdefg" as the match and the input is "abczzzz" you want "abc" as output? I would recommend not using Regex but simple single-character compare for that.

Comment: yes - and lets say the string was: "zzbbabc" and my matcher was: zbba, it would only match "z"... keep in mind that my matcher is dynamic, it changes each iteration.. so I can match the first? plus sequentially everythign after as long as its in order. given previous example, if my matcher was "zzbzb", it would only match "zzb".

Comment: Okay, so I would really recommend just comparing each character until one does not match, not using regex.

Comment: Your examples look a bit confused, but if you want to match a prefix of a given string with a regex, you'd have to generate something like `a(?:b(?:c(?:d(?:e)?)?)?)?` if your string is `abcde`.

Comment: In JS, it is next to impossible to do with regex as it does not support a look-behind. See a [PCRE-based regex solution](https://regex101.com/r/aD2uY0/1). It can be ported to JS with string reversal, but I think there is a cleaner way without a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I still think a non-regex-approach is best here. Have a look at the following JS-Code:

```
var match = "abcdef";
var input = "abcxdef";

var mArray = match.split("");
var inArray = input.split("");

var max = Math.min(mArray.length, inArray.length) - 1;

for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if (mArray[i] != inArray[i]) { break; }
}

input.substring(0, i);
```

Where match is the string to be partially matched, input is the input and `input.substring(0, i)` is the result of the matching part. And you can change match as often as you like.

Comment: Thanks phillip -- I see where you are going and truth be told, I could solve my problem easily if I just did simple string compares via  loop - but I want to go down a different route. One for learning, and two - just to find a different solution than what most would come up with. Thansk for your response though. Upped for your willingness to help!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, maybe you should add that to your question.